# React component with SVG does not evaluate expression

Tags: reactjs

Imagine I have a component like this it encloses an SVG:

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: "Initial message"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return ( < svg xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width = "300"
      height = "450" >
      < rect x = "0"
      y = "0"
      width = "300"
      height = "450"
      fill = "#d0d0d0" / >

      < text id = "textInHere"
      x = "50%"
      y = "50%"
      fill = "#7d7d7d" > {this.state.message} < /text> < /svg > )
  }

}
```

I am simply evaluating expression `this.state.message` as inner text.
To my surprise it generates the following DOM structure:

[image]

This is strange as i have not added any span!

The problem is illustrated in a plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/E6L8b3udpY0349ykSrlb?p=preview)

Appreciate, if any one could explain why I see multiple spans, and/or how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with whitespaces in your tags. When you remove them everything looks fine.

UPDATE: apparently, this is caused by spaces surrounding `{this.state.message}`. They are converted to `span` which results in breaking your syntax as you have observed (because `span` is not allowed inside `svg` tag).

Comment: Thanks! white spaces was the issue. corrected plunk here
https://plnkr.co/edit/pHPCOLbSgdXJ4tpnfEAQ?p=preview